# string after <span> shown with quotes in dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome dev tools.
I see two different ways my span element is shown in dev tools (based on the way it is being rendered in backend. I don't have the details about this)

1.

```
<span>    
    random text with some whitespace </span>
```

I don't see any expand button (an arrow that looks like |> in chrome dev tools) on this span.

2. Same text shown as this:

```
<span> "                 
                 
              random text with too much whitespace and quotes   

    "
</span>
```

This span has an expand arrow.

**What the backend is doing: This might be a helpful hint**:

It is a JSP page.

In case 1. If the text contains an anchor tag, it is rendered as plain text and not an actual link by the backend UI rendering framework

In case 2. it shows up as a link correctly

The UI rendering framework uses custom tag like

Adding anchor tag here causes it to show up as proper link

There is extra whitespace in 2. but UI is exactly the same in both.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: That's just what happens in DevTools. It's likely because it's a long long piece of text, and quite often, they don't want you thinking it might be code, because that could get confusing. _I'm no expert at DevTools, but good question._

Comment: What anchor tag?

Comment: @wazz Edited question to add more detail